# Programatically Generating OLAP Cube on PostgreSQL With Java

Tags: java, postgresql, analytics, olap-cube

Is there any way to accomplish the following behaviour with PostgreSQL and Java:

Imagine you have 2 tables:
`Transactions` and `Users`. `Transactions` hold some transaction data, while `Users`, obviously, hold user data.
Those 2 tables can be joined on `Users.ID == Transactions.UserID` condition.

Since there are quite few columns in that joined table, I want to do some analyzing.

For example, I'd like to know how many transactions has each used done. Naturally, you'd write something like this:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionID)
FROM Users NATURAL JOIN Transactions
GROUP BY UserID;
```

However, let's also say I would like to get some info about transactions per currency used.

```
SELECT Currency, COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionID)
FROM Users NATURAL JOIN Transactions
GROUP BY Currency;
```

Or how many times has each user paid with each currency:

```
SELECT UserID, Currency, COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionsID) AS NumTransactions
FROM Users NATURAL JOIN Transactions
GROUP BY UserID, Currency;
```

But now, given this last SQL, I can achieve any of the 2 previous ones like this:

First, I create a table from the previous SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE PerUserCurrencyStats AS
SELECT UserID, Currency, COUNT(DISTINCT TransactionsID) AS NumTransactions, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount  
FROM Users NATURAL JOIN Transactions
GROUP BY UserID, Currency;
```

Then I reduce the dimension and sum what I need to sum:

```
CREATE TABLE PerUserTransactionCount AS
SELECT UserID, SUM(NumTransactions)
FROM PerUserCurrencyStats
GROUP BY UserID;
```

OK, so where is the question?
Well, this really looks like OLAP Cube to me (take notice there are other columns/dimensions I wish to do analysis for).

Since I'm limited to using PostgreSQL and to generate such tables on the fly, I was wondering if there is way to do this, in my Java code, through calling SQL commands, but without writing all this tedious code myself?

Answer (score 3):

It can be a little tedious to write all this sql code. As you mentioned Olap cube i suggest you to use mondrian.

You can embed a molap engine in your java code with [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php).

You have to describe cubes, dimensions, measures in a schema file used in your java code.

[Here's](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?49874-Simple-JAVA-client-MONDRIAN) a code snippet.

```
package project1;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import mondrian.olap.Connection;
import mondrian.olap.DriverManager;
import mondrian.olap.Query;
import mondrian.olap.Result;

public class imondrian {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectString = "Provider=mondrian;" 
            + "Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodmart?user=foodmart&password=foodmart;" 
            + "Catalog=file:/path/to/file/FoodMart.xml;"
            + "JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        System.out.println(connectString);

        Connection connection = null;

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, null, false);
        Query query = connection.parseQuery(
            "SELECT {[Measures].[Unit Sales], [Measures].[Store Cost], [Measures].[Store Sales]} on columns," 
                + "{([Promotion Media].[All Media], [Product].[All Products])} ON rows "
                + "FROM Sales "
                + "WHERE ([Time].[1997])"
        ); 

        Result result = connection.execute(query);

        result.print(new PrintWriter(System.out,true)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bruno. I will give this a shot and see if it fits my needs. In the meantime, here's an upvote :D